# How to call multiple templates in single component using angular2

Tags: templates, angular, routes, components

I am new to angularJs2. My requirement is that I want multiple templates in single component. Like I have `ForgetPasswordComponent` and there are two routes with name `forgot-password` and `password/reset`. So I want to call diff-diff templates on diff routes. Currently the `forgot-password.component.html` is calling on `forgot-password` route and now I want to call diff. template on `password/reset` route. *Here is my code.*

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
 { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgetPasswordComponent },
{ path: 'password/reset', component: ForgetPasswordComponent },
```

**forget-password.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AlertService, AuthenticationService, ForgotpasswordService } from '../_services/index';
//import { AppSettings,IEnvVars } from '../_configs/app.settings';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: '../templates/forgot-password.component.html',
  providers:[AlertService, AuthenticationService,  ForgotpasswordService]
 })

export class ForgetPasswordComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = {};
  loading = false;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private forgotpasswordService: ForgotpasswordService,
    private alertService: AlertService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // reset login status
    this.authenticationService.logout();
  }

  forgotPassword() {

    this.loading = true;
    this.forgotpasswordService.forgotPassword(this.model.email)
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log("yesss"),
            error => {
               console.log("yesss");
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if NG2 has built-in way to support this. My solution is inheritance. I just used a base component class to contain all or most logic and data, without a html template. Then in derived component classes, just need to declare constructor calling super(...), and define respective html template.

If your application is complex, likely you will be using module to instantiate classes, then make sure you declare moduleId: module.id in the Component attribute, otherwise the NG2 runtime may complain the html template could not be loaded.